# Macbook 2007 UK - Enter/Return Key Not working

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I've been trying to install Ubuntu onto a Macbook 2007.
I've managed to get it to install, using a custom boot disk from mattgadient, which seems to allow it to install (I struggled with lack of ESD and still don't really get it).
But no matter which keyboard I install, the Enter key won't register.
If I reinstall OSX 10.6 or Cloudready the key works fine, but in Ubuntu, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that a key called "Projective, with Unicode U+2305" is working as the return or enter key. Looks like this. ⌤
The carriage return is not working. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi David, I've tried 18.04 and 20.04. Both seem to do the same.